# Is it safe to return an array created in a function in Julia

Tags: arrays, function, scope, return, julia

I'm doing something like this in Julia:

```
function(params)
  vector = Float64[]
  .
  .
  push!(vector, something)
  .
  .
  return vector
end
```

is it safe to do that or will the allocated memory be released?
My program works, is it an accident?

Is it perhaps safer to pass the vector to the function as a parameter like

```
function(params, vector)
  .
  .
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Both ways should work. If you do pass the vector as an input to the function, and then modify it in-place, it is the convention to append an exclamation mark to the name of the function. For example, `normalize` returns a normalized copy of the input vector, while `normalize!` updates the input vector in-place.

Comment: Yes, it is safe. All Julia arrays are allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe. When you do something like

```
newvector = function(params)
```

the variable `newvector` still refers to the array you've created in your function, so it will not be garbage-collected.

Comment: Moreover, making this safe is precisely why garbage collection exists in programming languages.